# how to insert data updatable by both sender and receiver?

Tags: solidity, web3js, react

---------Solidity---------

```
struct Requests
{ 
    string status; // accepted | pending | rejected
    string amount; // 1,000,000 PINE
    string description; //
}

mapping (address => Requests[]) public Rqst;
```

This is a create request:

```
function createRequest(Requests memory rqst) external
{
        Rqst[msg.sender].push(Requests({
            status:rqst.status,
            amount:rqst.amount,
            description:rqst.description
        }));
}
```

This is the get request:

```
function getRequest(uint requestIndex) external view returns (Requests memory)
{
        Requests storage rqst = Rqst[msg.sender][requestIndex];
        return rqst;
}
```

Update request

```
function updateRequest(uint256 requestIndex, Requests memory bar) external 
{
    Rqst[msg.sender][requestIndex].status = bar.status;
    Rqst[msg.sender][requestIndex].amount = bar.amount;
    Rqst[msg.sender][requestIndex].description = bar.description;
}
```

---------end of Solidity---------

---------React.js---------

```
  const createRequest =  async () => {
    await contract.methods.createRequest(['pending',amount, description]).send({ from: defaultAccount });
  }
```

Note: in createRequest, defaultAccount is the current metamask login, which is the employee.

This method getRequests is called if the metamask login is the manager.

```
  const getRequests =  async (contract, defaultAccount) => {
    const f = async () => {
      const len = await contract.methods.getRequestount().call({ from: defaultAccount });
      console.log("len",len)
      let iterator = 0
      let contain = []
      while ( iterator <= len) {
        try {
          console.log("iterator",iterator)
          let o = await contract.methods.getRequest(String(iterator)).call({ from: defaultAccount });
          if (o[0] !== '') {
            contain.push({
              status: o['status'],
              amount: o['amount'],
              description: o['description']
            })
          }
          else {
            console.log('The index ' + iterator + ' is empty');
          }
        } catch {
          console.log('Failed to get requests ' + iterator);
        }
        iterator++;
      }
      return contain
    }
    let c = await f()
    dispatch(setRequests(c))
  }
```

----------end of React.js--------

I am creating a request to my manager.
The manager has an admin that displays a list of request.

When I `getRequest()` web3 returns `MetaMask - RPC Error: execution reverted`.

I tried creating request using the manager and then display the requests, it works perfectly.

Comment: ive updated my content, i added the mapping and struct, thanks @RyanSea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal seems to be to allow a manager to get and update an employee's request.

You should add a param for the employee's address

```
function getRequest(address employee, uint requestIndex) external view returns (Requests memory) {
        Requests storage rqst = Rqst[employee][requestIndex];
        return rqst;
}
```

This will return a request at a given index.

To return all requests from an employee you could do this:

```
function getRequests(address employee) external view returns (Requests[] memory) {
        return Rqst[employee];
}
```

Similarly, to update the request of an employee, you should add a parameter for the employee's address

Feel free to add a variable for the manager `address public manager;`, set the manager at the constructor

```
// This will set the deployer of the contract as manager
constructor() {manager = msg.sender}
```

And permission updateRequest

```
    function updateRequest(
      address employee, 
      uint256 requestIndex, 
      Requests memory bar
    ) external {
      require(msg.sender == employee || msg.sender == manager, "NOT_ALLOWED")

      Rqst[employee][requestIndex].status = bar.status;
      Rqst[employee][requestIndex].amount = bar.amount;
      Rqst[employee][requestIndex].description = bar.description;

    }
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, but i made a mistake there shouldnt be an index there.

Comment: This request is only available to the sender. what happens if i change account and `updateReqeuest()` it will cause error, this is my main problem

Comment: how to insert data updatable by both sender and receiver?

Comment: @ichimaru So you want a user A to be able to update user B's request?

Comment: correct, thats on point

Comment: watching this tutorial right now https://youtu.be/EhPeHeoKF88?t=3034

Comment: this is method from dapp university is more secure,
https://github.com/dappuniversity/master_solidity/blob/master/examples/6_HotelRoom.sol. `book()` method is something im looking for

Comment: @ichimaru edited for security

Comment: base on my solidity, is there any to make both parties update the request?

Comment: @ichimaru the require statement I wrote allows both parties to update the request

Comment: i tried it, i cant update the request using the managers account, here is my sol file, https://github.com/ollolollollooloo/storage/blob/main/pops.sol

Comment: can i just get the getRequests() of all employee? i dont have to pass the address of an employee

Comment: @ichimaru You can create a `address[] public employees;`, push msg.sender to employees every time createRequest is run, and create a view function for `getAllEmployees()` that returns an `address[]` of `employees`, then iterate through that with `getRequests(address)`

Comment: after hours of analyzing and testing, i finally get it now, its working, thank you!